# Clarification for terminology: Standard representation of $S_n$ and a related representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, terminology

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of order $n$. Then the map $\rho$ sending $\sigma \in S_n$ to its corresponding permutation matrix is a representation. It's not irreducible, but

$$\rho = \psi \oplus \mathbf{1}$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ is the trivial representation, and $\psi$ is another representation which is irreducible.

In my notes from lectures, I wrote that $\rho$ was the representation referred to as the "standard representation of $S_n$", but online resources say $\psi$ would be the one called te "standard representation".

Which is correct? Indeed,

- If $\rho$ is the one called the standard representation, what is the name for $\psi$ (if there is one)?
- If $\psi$ is the one called the standard representation, what is the name for $\rho$ (if there is one)?

Comment: I found https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_the_symmetric_group and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258486. So $\psi$ is the standard one.

Comment: Personally, I don't find the terminology *standard* particularly descriptive here. I prefer to use *permutation representation* for the representation of the symmetric group on $\mathbf{C}^n$ given by permutation of coordinates, and *irreducible reflection representation* for the summand you specify.